Triple inequality
How do you write triple inequality in Latex? If "\equiv" stands for triple equality

For example mathabx has \notequiv. Can you show a small test file so we can see which packages you use and if one of them might already have this symbol?

Or simply \not\equiv with standard fonts.

In \usepackage{amssymb}?

\not\equiv works. Many thanks for the comments and help!

@campa yes, thanks for the source/reference!
